# Windows 10 is not letting me use a custom keyboard Layout

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10, desktop, custom-keyboard

I've been trying to change my keyboard layout to Colemak for the last days with little success. I did everything in Microsoft Layout keyboard creator even thought it's a decade old and i managed to get to the point where i have the file, it shows up in settings, but if it's the only layout in a language i can't use it and if there's multiple it doesn't choose Colemak even if it's at the top

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I restarted and then it started working. I set my keyboard layout to the only layout in a language. I'm not sure if works for having the layout as the first one in a list, but theoretically it should work.